# how to call function inside axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am trying to call a function inside Axios but it showing undefined. Below is my simple code.i am using vuejs.

```
methods:{
    sett( ){
        console.log("result" )
    },

    List() {
        var self = this;
        axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/pas/device")
            .then(function(res) {
                self.sett( )
            }
        }
    },
    created: {
        this.List();
    }
```

Comment: Please add some more code to understand

Comment: try using await
const list = await axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/pas/device");
 this.sett()

Comment: my answer was the first and the correct one, please check the time of each answer

Comment: You should accept and upvote the first and correct answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arrow function in axios and invoke other functions in regular way:

```
methods:{
  sett( ){
    console.log("result" )
  },
  List() {
    axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/pas/device")
        .then((res) => {
            this.sett();  // do with res what you want
        });
  }
},
created() {
    this.List();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Created is a function

```
methods:{
   sett(response){
       console.log(response)
       console.log("result" )
   },
},
created() {
   axios.get("http://localhost:8080/api/v1/pas/device").then(this.sett)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`created` hook is a function not an object :

```
....
created:function(){
  this.List()
}
```

or the ES6 shorthand syntax :

```
....
created(){
  this.List()
}
```